# installing gcc-4.6.3 instead of gcc-13.2.0 on linux

Tags: c, gcc, installation

Can you tell me how to configure the old version of gcc-4.6.3 on Linux? I have already downloaded and launched it. Now I have a gcc directory that contains bin and stuff. The old gcc-4.6.3 is installed on /home/usr. However, I do not understand how to change the current gcc-13.2.0 to gcc-4.6.3. I tried to add the line “export PATH=/home/usr/gcc/bin/$PATH" to the files.bashrc and .zshrc tried to delete the current version of gcc, but every time when checking the gcc version it showed that it was missing or remained 13.2.0. What could be the problem?

Comment: Replacing your system installed compiler seems like a very bad idea.  Modern code won't compile with such an old compiler.  If you really do need the antique version for something specific, then keep it in a separate directory to use for that task (and just run `/home/usr/gcc/bin/gcc` to execute it), and leave the system compiler alone.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I don't understand all this well, can you tell me exactly how to run /home/usr/gcc/bin/gcc to execute?

Comment: Type `/home/usr/gcc/bin/gcc foo.c -o foo` at your shell prompt, where `foo.c` is your source file.

Comment: @NateEldredge he needs to set sysroot as well

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same as your [previously deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648220/installing-gcc-on-kali-linux) with all mentions of kali linux removed.  If you want help you need to 1) describe, in detail, exactly what you're trying to achieve 2) show what you've tried so far and 3) describe the problem(s) you encountered.